# Combining multple figure in window

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm playing around with kaggle dataframe to practice using `matplotlib`.

I was creating bar graph one by one, but it keeps adding up.

When I called `plt.show()` there were like 10 windows of figure suddenly shows up.

Is it possible to combine 4 of those figures into 1 window?

These part are in the same segments "Time Analysis" So I want to combine these 4 figures in 1 window.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

dataset  = ('accidents_data.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(dataset)

"""Time Analysis :
Analyze the time that accidents happen for various patterns and trends"""
df.Start_Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Start_Time)  #convert the start time column to date time format
df['Hour_of_Accident'] = df.Start_Time.dt.hour #extract the hour from the time data

hour_accident = df['Hour_of_Accident'].value_counts()
hour_accident_df = hour_accident.to_frame() #convert the series data to dataframe in order to sort the index columns
hour_accident_df.index.names = ['Hours'] #naming the index column
hour_accident_df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(hour_accident_df)

# Plotting the hour of accidents data in a bargraph
hour_accident_df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(8,4),color='blue',title='Hour of Accident')
#plt.show() #Show the bar graph


"""Analyzing the accident frequency per day of the week"""
df['Day_of_the_week'] = df.Start_Time.dt.day_of_week
day_of_accident = df['Day_of_the_week'].value_counts()

day_of_accident_df = day_of_accident.to_frame() #convert the series data  to  dataframe so that we can sort the index columns
day_of_accident_df.index.names = ['Day'] # Renaming the index column
day_of_accident_df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(day_of_accident_df)


f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8, 5))
x = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Sartuday', 'Sunday']
l = day_of_accident_df.index.values
y = day_of_accident_df.Day_of_the_week

plt.bar(l, y, color='green')
plt.title('Day of the week vs total number of accidents')
plt.ylabel("No. of accidents recorded")
ax.set_xticks(l)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
#plt.show()

"""Analysis for the months"""
df['Month'] = df.Start_Time.dt.month
accident_month = df['Month'].value_counts()

accident_month_df = accident_month.to_frame() #convert the series data  to  dataframe so that we can sort the index columns
accident_month_df.index.names = ['Month'] # Renaming the index column
accident_month_df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(accident_month_df)

#Plotting the Bar Graph
accident_month_df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(8,5),color='purple',title='Month of Accident')

"""Yearly Analysis"""
df['Year_of_accident'] = df.Start_Time.dt.year
#Check the yearly trend
yearly_count = df['Year_of_accident'].value_counts()
yearly_count_df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':yearly_count.index, 'Accidents':yearly_count.values})
yearly_count_df.sort_values(by='Year', ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(yearly_count_df)
#Creating line plot
yearly_count_df.plot.line(x='Year',color='red',title='Yearly Accident Trend ')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried 
`fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2,figsize=(15,15))
hour_accident_df.plot(ax = axes[1],kind='bar',figsize=(8,4),color='blue',title='Hour of Accident')`

got error message "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'"

Comment: With multiple rows and multiple columns, `axes` is 2D, so `plot(..., ax=axes[1, 0])`